# How to identify the InAppPurchase alerts

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

i am doing one application.In that i am using IAP concept.In that once user finish the subscription, i am calling the proideContent method. And if user again try to subscribe before end of subscription i need to call that method. But in that time i am getting the alert from apple like "**Already subscribed**" with Ok button. If i click that button failed transaction method is firing. If i call provideContent method at here then this will calling when the user cancel the transaction at the first time. So hoe to identify the IAP "**Already subscribed alert**"

Comment: What class is the provideContent method from? What type of in-app purchase product do you have?

Comment: with in the same class i call that method to provide the subscribed content.I am implementing auto renewal subscription.