# How to identify the IAP Allready subscribed alert

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

i am doing one application.In that i am using IAP concept.In that,once user finish the subscription,i am calling the proideContent method. And if user again try to subscribe before end of subscription i need to call that provideContent method. But in that time i am getting the alert from apple like "Already subscribed" with Ok button. But i am unable to identify alert belongs to "Already subscribed". So how can we identify that alert.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is provideContent method? Please share some code. What have you tried?

Comment: How it differ from your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22197816/how-to-identify-the-inapppurchase-alerts

Comment: In that method i am providing the subscribed data to user.I can call that method when the subscribe is over.